# Using string function in DLL file made in Delphi 11 from Delphi 7 host application runs into 'invalid pointer operation' error

Tags: delphi, dll

I have developed a DLL file in Delphi 11 and would like to use it from a Delphi 7 application. However, I am encountering some issues.

When creating a host application in Delphi 11, I can use the following code to use my DLL function:

```
type
  TMergeText = function(t1, t2: String): String; stdcall;

procedure TForm1.btnMergeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  handle: THandle;
  MergeText: TMergeText;
  LNewText: String;
begin
  handle := LoadLibrary(PChar(dll_path));
  if handle <> 0 then
  begin
    @MergeText := GetProcAddress(handle, 'MergeText');
    if @MergeText <> nil then
    begin
      LNewText := MergeText(edText1.Text, edText2.Text);
      edMerged.Text := LNewText;
    end;
    FreeLibrary(handle);
  end;
end;
```

When I use this code in my Delphi 7 application, I encounter the following error message when executing the command `FreeLibrary(handle)`:

```
Project HostProgramDLL.exe raised exception class EInvalidPointer with message 'Invalid pointer operation'.
```

Both my Delphi 11 and Delphi 7 projects are equipped with ShareMem, and the DLL project also has ShareMem included.

When I use another function, just with some integers adding up, everything seems to work fine. Therefore, I assume the problems occur when using string values as function parameters and results, but I’m not sure.

Could you please help me identify the root cause of this issue and suggest a solution?

Comment: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html

Comment: Strings have never been appropriate for use in DLL calls. Use an appropriate type such as PChar. This is documented, and this information is available in many existing posts here at SO. This is an unacceptable practice even when the DLL and EXE are compiled with versions of Delphi with compatible string types, which D7 and D11 do not.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 7 `String` type is `AnsiString`, whereas newer Delphi versions (from D2009) use`String=UnicodeString`, so you try to move distinct types between EXE and DLL.

Moreover, `AnsiString`'s in D7 and modern versions a) have different intrinsic structure b) are managed with distinct memory managers, so `Sharemem` doesn't solve all possible memory management issues.

It would be wise to provide the same simple (not managed) type at the both ends - `PWideChar` or `PAnsiChar`.

Also it is worth to mention `Widestring` type, it implements system `BSTR` intended for COM interaction and is managed by operation system.

Comment: Even with that, using such advanced, managed types as strings is risky. I doubt that ShareMem from two different Delphi versions would be possible to use (just a guess here, not a fact). You would be much safer with a simple datatype, such as a pointer to an array of bytes (and a clear definition of which side manages the memory).

Comment: @MatthiasB Perhaps you are right. That is why I mentioned PWideChar as preferable type. As far as I remember, Widestring is based on BSTR system type and is managed by system (cannot check just now, Emba site is down). But for AnsiString  I am not sure in correct work with distinct memory managers.

Comment: @MBo you are correct, `WideString=BSTR`

Comment: Don't think AnsiString has the same metadata. For instance in Unicode delphi there is the code page but that's not carried around in the string for ANSI delphis. There's the germ of an answer here, but this should be converted to a comment, or made complete.

Comment: Sharemem will not work. D7 uses AnsiString as its string type, while later versions use Unicode strings. This makes the string types incompatible.